# javacc,why ' return jjtThis '

Tags: javacc

Why  write `return jjtThis`  at the end of the methods?
What effect will it make?
What if I don't write this line?
When should I add this line and when shouldn't I add this line?
Is it `return` for the judge of other place?

```
ASTDirectSQLStatement DirectSQLStatement() :
{}
{
DirectlyExecutableStatement() <SEMICOLON>
{
    return jjtThis;
}
}

ASTDirectlyExecutableStatement DirectlyExecutableStatement() :
{}
{ (
LOOKAHEAD(<SELECT> | <DELETE> <FROM> | <INSERT> | <UPDATE> | <DECLARE>)
DirectSQLDataStatement()
| LOOKAHEAD(SQLSchemaStatement())
SQLSchemaStatement()
)
{
  return jjtThis;
}
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I think it is actually rather unusual to return jjtThis. Is this in a .jjt file, in a .jj file generated from a .jjt file, or in a .jj file not generated from a .jjt file?

Comment: my misstake , it is in a .jjt file

Comment: Ok.  As I said, it is weird to return jjtThis.  Can you ask the person who wrote the jjt file?

Comment: I cann't find the person hehe.  thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, *jjtThis* is a special identifier of *SimpleNode* class, that refers to the Function/Production it is written inside of. We use/return jjtThis when we generate a parse tree or AST. In your example; *DirectSQLStatement* production is a node in a tree, this production calls another production *DirectlyExecutableStatement* which will be *DirectSQLStatement's* child node in the tree, *DirectlyExecutableStatement* then calls some other production(s) which will be its children so on so forth.

SimpleNode is the class that makes your tree. Usually *jjtThis* is returned only from the first production/function of grammar and in main() you have a *SimpleNode's* object say "root" that catches it. Then by root.Dump(" ") the tree is printed. Hope it helps!